# Write multiple lines to a file using bash for Mac

Tags: macos, bash, sh

I am creating a bash file to be run in Mac PC. Basically the file creates and writes multiple lines to a file. It contains some special characters like tilde, percentage etc.

Somehow in the file created, the characters sometimes disappears or appears wrong. I am doing the standard echo line by line. E.g.

```
echo text >> file.conf
```

Is there any other way to write to a file?

Comment: Maybe `echo -e "your_text" >> file.conf` will work?

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Comment: @MarkSetchell For now I am testing it using hardcoded data. So it is specified inside the bash file itself.

Comment: You should show us what characters are giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting your text. If you want variables expanded, use double quotes. If you do not want variables expanded, use single quotes:

```
echo "$HOME"   # expanded
/Users/Mark

echo '$HOME'   # not expanded
$HOME

echo *         # expanded
0.jpg 0_0.jpg 0_1.jpg 0_10.jpg 0_11.jpg 0_12.jpg 0_2.jpg 0_3.jpg 0_4.jpg

echo '*'       # not expanded
*
```

Comment: Your last example uses back ticks (back quotes). That is syntax for executing a command in a subshell. It is dangerous and probably not what you intended. In your example, it will try to run the command `0.jpg 0_0.jpg 0_1.jpg 0_10.jpg 0_11.jpg 0_12.jpg 0_2.jpg 0_3.jpg 0_4.jpg`. If the first file were actually executable, that could do bad things.

Comment: @KenThomases Thank you for pointing that out - I need to be more careful on my iPhone keyboard!